# How to create dataset with ordered and hierarchically-grouped rows?

Tags: dataset, grid-layouts

The (toy-example) dataset `plots` consists of 12 rows, the first two of which are shown below:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to arrange the plots shown in the `plot` column into a grid, where the rows correspond to values of the `color` and `suit` variables, and the columns correspond to the values of the `elf` variable.

More specifically, the rows should be grouped into two "superrows", one for each value of the `color` variable, in the order `{"red", "black"}`, and the rows within each superrow should correspond to the values of the `suit` variable, ordered alphabetically.

I've only managed to achieve a simple grid, where the rows are neither grouped nor ordered:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's the code that does it:

```
grid = plots[GroupBy["suit"], GroupBy[KeyDrop[#, "suit"], Key["elf"], Function[x, First[x][["plot"]]]] &];
```

(I'd be embarrassed to admit how many hours it took me to conquer this molehill.)

---

My questions are:

1. How can I create the superrows?
2. How can I display the labels of the rows and superrows as two hierarchical header columns along the left?
3. How can I order the two levels as described above?

---

FWIW, below is the code that generates the `plots` dataset.

```
makeDataset[columns_, columnLabels_] := Module[{labeledColumns, records},
   labeledColumns = AssociationThread[columnLabels, columns];
   records = Transpose[labeledColumns, AllowedHeads -> All];
   Dataset[records]
];

preplots = Module[{points, data, base, columns, columnNames, validCombinationPattern, validRows},
   points = Flatten[Table[Table[Chop[{Sin[m (u + 2)], Sin[n u]}], {u, 0, 4 \[Pi], 0.1}],
                          {n, 4}, {m, 3}], 1];
   data = Map[makeDataset[Transpose[#], {"x", "y"}] &, points];

   base = <|"suit" -> {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"},
            "color" -> {"Black", "Red"},
            "elf" -> {"Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"}|>;

   validCombinationPattern = {"Spades" | "Clubs", "Black", _} | {"Hearts" | "Diamonds", "Red", _};
   validRows = Cases[Tuples[Values[base]], validCombinationPattern];
   columns = Append[Transpose[validRows], data];
   columnNames = Append[Keys[base], "data"];

   makeDataset[columns, columnNames]
];

doPlot[dataset_] := ListPlot[dataset[["data"]], AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None];
plots = preplots[All, KeyDrop[Append[#, "plot" -> doPlot[#]], "data"] &];
```

---

**Update**

Here's the *seed* of an idea regarding the problem (mentioned by WReach) of the repeated column headers.

One can use the part spec `[[All, Values]]` on the 2nd-level datasets to effectively suppress the column headers:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code for that is the following modification of WReach's pipeline:

```
plots[
  GroupBy[{#color&, #suit&, #elf& -> (#plot&)}] /* KeySortBy[<|"Red"->1,"Black"->2|>]
, KeySort /* KeyMap[Pane[#, 50] &] /* (Dataset[#][[All, Values]] &)
, KeySort
, First
]
```

(Actually, for the figure shown, I had to use a width of 70 rather than 50 for the `suit` header.  YMMV.)

What I still have not figured out how to do is to apply this modification selectively to all but the first superrow.

---

**Lingering minor gripe:** the `2 levels | 2 rows`, &c. schmutz at the bottom of the dataframes is an unwelcome distraction.  I wish one could suppress it somehow.  To WRI: This `... levels | ... rows` information is of interest only for debugging; once the dataset's structure is as it should be, and its *contents* are clearly displayed, one couldn't care less about the `... levels | ... rows` information.  Please add "remove levels/rows annotation from default Dataset display" to the wishlist for 10.5.

Comment: An unofficial (and unsupported) way to suppress the summary bar at the bottom of a dataset visualization is ``Block[{Dataset`$DatasetSummaryBarEnabled = False}, Print@mydataset]``.  Note the use of `Print` to force box generation while the global variable is set.  If you never want to see the summary boxes ever, you can simply set the global value of the variable by direct assignment instead of using `Block`.  Also, beware that this variable must be set _after_ the ``Dataset` `` package has been loaded.

Comment: @WReach: many thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update - Version 11**

In version 11, The `Dataset` visualizer handles triply-nested associations quite nicely:

```
plots[
  GroupBy[{#color&, #suit&, #elf& -> (#plot&)}] /* KeySortBy[<|"Red"->1, "Black"->2|>]
, KeySort
, KeySort
, First
]
```

[image: triply-nested dataset screenshot]

---

**Original Response**

The `Dataset` visualizer does not presently (v10.4.1) support a nice layout for triply-nested associations.  However, we can get close by nesting datasets:

```
plots[
  GroupBy[{#color&, #suit&, #elf& -> (#plot&)}] /* KeySortBy[<|"Red"->1,"Black"->2|>]
, KeySort /* Dataset
, KeySort
, First
]
```

[image: triply-nested association dataset screenshot]

`KeySort` and `KeySortBy` are used at each association level to order the keys.

This rendition is not perfect, but has the virtue of being achievable with relatively simple code.  We can get better alignment of the columns by using `Pane` to fix the width of the suit row headers:

```
plots[
  GroupBy[{#color&, #suit&, #elf& -> (#plot&)}] /* KeySortBy[<|"Red"->1,"Black"->2|>]
, KeySort /* KeyMap[Pane[#, 50]&] /* Dataset
, KeySort
, First
]
```

[image: dataset with columns aligned]

The repeated headers are harder to fix.  It requires, for example, creating a new visualization from scratch using `Grid` (left as an exercise for the reader :).

**Bug In *Mathematica* 10.2 and Earlier**

In *Mathematica* version 10.2, a bug in the `Dataset` type system will prevent the exhibited expressions from working properly.  To dodge the bug, we must use the usual work-around when faced with a type-error in `Dataset`: extract the data from the `Dataset`, transform it, and then stuff it back into a new `Dataset`:

```
plots// Normal // Query[
  GroupBy[{#color&, #suit&, #elf& -> (#plot&)}] /*
    KeySortBy[<|"Red"->1,"Black"->2|>] /* Dataset
, KeySort /* KeyMap[Pane[#, 50]&] /* Dataset
, KeySort
, First
]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I learned a lot from studying your code.  Also, I updated my post to include an idea for how to deal with the repeated column headers (it gets only halfway there, though).

Comment: BTW, your code is very clear, a rarity in the *Mathematica* world (ironically enough, given WRI's titanic efforts to support the "literate programming" ideal).  In particular, your idea of beginning lines with the separator works really well here.